# How can you sum up the amount of items in a month?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

[image]I have a data set that records in each row a particular item and the day it was entered. In this example set, I want to figure out how to sum the number of bananas and oranges that occur in a particular month. I am able to write a formula to count the total amount of entries in a month, but I am stuck on how to do that per month, and then per item. The cells highlighted yellow are where I'm stuck.

To find the total amount of entries per month, I have used (for example in cell F4):

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(A4:A21) = D4)*(YEAR(A4:A21) = B1))
```

To find the total amount of each type of fruit, I have tried:

To find the total amount of a particular fruit in a particular month I have tried (for example, in cell H4):

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(1*(MONTH(A4:A21)=D4)), COUNTIF(B4:B21, "Bananas"), "")
```

But my problem is that this is just summing the total amount of Bananas across all months, it's not specifically for a single month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=QUERY(QUERY(A$4:B, "where month (A)+1="&MONTH(E4&1)), 
 "select Col2, count(Col2) group by Col2 label count(Col2)''")
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Is it possible to use the QUERY function to find the sum of two different months? For example, the amount of bananas in both February and March?

Comment: sure: `=QUERY(QUERY(A$4:B, "where month (A)+1=2 and month (A)+1=3), 
 "select Col2, count(Col2) group by Col2 label count(Col2)''")`

Answer (score 1):

Use Countifs.
For example, to get the number of bananas in Feb:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,D4,B:B,G4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given a pivot table can (easily, dynamically and with versatility) return:

[image]

others with a very similar requirement my prefer a different solution.